# How do I open the Xcode programming environment in Windows?

Tags: windows, xcode

I'm having trouble opening Xcode 9 beta 4 on my Windows computer. It's the first time I've tried downloading Xcode, and I think the problem may be my computer isn't able to open .xip files but I'm not confident. Any insight or advice?

Comment: xcode doesnt work on windows.. It works only in mac environment

Answer (score 2):

**Xcode can not run on Windows**

You will need to install macOS/OSX in a virtual environment, like VMWare or VirtualBox in order to use Xcode on Windows.  https://blog.udemy.com/xcode-on-windows/  Alternatively you could look into other IDEs that allow cross-compiling if you want to code on windows but deploy on mac.  See this previous question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/693952/how-to-compile-for-os-x-in-linux-or-windows

Comment: Note that installing and running macOS on anything but an actual Mac violates Apple's license and is also off topic for Ask Different. But there are other forums that specialize in Hackintoshes and running macOS in a VM

Comment: Note that the case law is far from settled about the EULA if you buy a physical DVD of the os.

Comment: I agree - it is good to point out clear points where a license could be invalid but we also don’t shut down questions that explain how to do many things that might be legal for research or something someone might consider worth the risk. It would be like deleting all posts about driving faster than 55 mph on unmarked highways in the US other than saying - be sure you understand the laws and penalties and enforcement mechanisms.